# With Python, how to access a vertex group created by parenting to an armature with auto weights?

Tags: python, rigging, armature, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have rigged a character and auto weighted the mesh to armatures. A set of vertex groups are generated from this way automatically.

However, I tried to get vertex_groups but failed.

```
len(D.objects['Armature'].vertex_groups)
```

returns 0

How can I get access to the vertex group generated?

Comment: Please answer only one question per Stack Exchange question. I've answered your first: how to access the vertex groups in Python. Creating a convex hull out of a vertex group and using that for collision detection is something else.

Comment: Thank you. I will post convex hull question separately if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The vertex groups are on the mesh object, not on the armature. The armature itself doesn't have any vertices.

```
>>> list(vg.name for vg in D.objects["Cube"].vertex_groups)
['Bone', 'Bone.001']
```